# Add provider to User federation in RedHat SSO/keycloak using CLI

Tags: keycloak

I have custom provider created and deployed.
Now I goto user federation select the drop down and add my provider using UI and fine. [Image using UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFk4h.png)

Can some one please let me know how to add the same using CLI as I want to automate the manual process.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
kcadm.bat create user-federation/instances -r Test1 \
-s providerName=tatts-asg-authentication \
-s priority=0 \
-s config.debug=false
```

Comment: In newer versions of Keycloak, `user-federation/instances` has been replaced with `components` https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-6583

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for **Keycloak 3.4.3**:

```
kcadm.bat create components -x -r MyRealm \
-s providerType=org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProvider \
-s name=my-provider \
-s parentId=MyRealm \
-s providerId=my-provider \
-s 'config.path=["C:\\path\\to\\properties"]' \
-s 'config.priority=["0"]'
```

`user-federation/instances` has been replaced with `components`: [issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-6583](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-6583)

The `-x` option is to output the stacktrace on error.